# How to align two div's next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have two field set that i would like to display next to one another :

[image]

I have managed to get it the correct distance i want from one another but have not been able to lineup there height.

Below is the html i have used.

```
<div style="width:900px; height:230px;">
  <fieldset style="width:150px;">
    <legend>Facilities Required</legend>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="PhysicalMailbox" runat="server" Text="Physical Mailbox" /><br>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Uniform" runat="server" Text="Uniform"/><br>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Desk" runat="server" Text="Desk"/><br>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Stationary" runat="server" Text="Stationary"/>
  </fieldset>
  <div style="width:50%; top:0px">
    <fieldset style="width:229px; left:151px; float:right; top:0px;" >
      <legend>Access Required</legend>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="AccessTag" runat="server" Text="Access Tag" /><br><br>
      <asp:Label ID="lblProfile" enableviewstate="false" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddProfile" CssClass="FormLabel">Profile</asp:Label>
      <ICCM:ICCMDropDownList ID="ddProfile" runat="server" TabIndex="10" style="width:233px;" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  >   
        <Items>
          <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" Selected="True" />    
        </Items>                                                                                                    
      </ICCM:ICCMDropDownList>
   </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's pretty easy @Pomster,Stackoverflow has so many question and answers about this task.dont have time to do web search??   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716955/css-layout-aligning-two-divs-side-by-side and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460990/align-2-divs-side-by-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you should create a new div which will be the container of rest two DIVs. The apply style "float: left" on inner DIVs. Have a look code below, this is working as you are expecting:

```
    <div style="width:900px">
        <div style="width:50%; height:230px; float:left;">
          <fieldset style="width:150px;">
            <legend>Facilities Required</legend>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PhysicalMailbox" runat="server" Text="Physical Mailbox" /><br>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Uniform" runat="server" Text="Uniform"/><br>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Desk" runat="server" Text="Desk"/><br>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Stationary" runat="server" Text="Stationary"/>
          </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div style="width:50%; top:0px;float:left;">
            <fieldset style="width:229px; left:151px; float:right; top:0px;" >
              <legend>Access Required</legend>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="AccessTag" runat="server" Text="Access Tag" /><br><br>
              <asp:Label ID="lblProfile" enableviewstate="false" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddProfile" CssClass="FormLabel">Profile</asp:Label>
              <ICCM:ICCMDropDownList ID="ddProfile" runat="server" TabIndex="10" style="width:233px;" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  >   
                <Items>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" Selected="True" />    
                </Items>                                                                                                    
              </ICCM:ICCMDropDownList>
           </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, this will work as container and their float property will on the basis on parent container. Also, you missed one close div tag after first fieldset.

Answer (score 1):

set them to:

```
  style="display:inline-block;"
```

correct whole code:

```
<div style="width:900px; height:230px;">
    <div style=" top:0px; display:inline-block;">
    <fieldset style="width:150px;">

    </fieldset>
    </div>
  <div style=" top:0px; display:inline-block;">
    <fieldset style="width:229px; left:151px; float:right; top:0px;" >

   </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The div or the fieldset??

Comment: the correct thing to do, is to put the fieldsets inside 2 divs with style="display:inline-block;" and specify their width. so in your case: one big container div, and 2 small divs inside and inside those 2 divs you pu the fieldsets

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap first `<fieldset>` into a `<div/>` and set it `float:left`

Give `float:left` to that `<div>`

*first fieldset*

```
<div style="float:left;"> 
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
</div>
```

Note: You forgot to close main `</div>`, Consider both `divs` one is `float:left` and another is `float:right` remove `float` from fieldset.

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C59Yj/)

***Another way*** is using `display` properties:

You can set `display:inline-block` to both the `divs` containing `fieldset`, you might have to consider `vertical-alignment` :)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fSTzV/)

Go for 2 `div's` like this :-

```
<div style="width:150px; height:230px;">Fieldset 1</div>
<div style="width: auto; height:230px;">Fieldset 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;`
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UzLDs/)